# Can creatures without hands (and as a consequence fingers) use rings?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, monsters

Pretty much what it says on a label. I have a monster for my next adventure that has a pretty interesting ring in his treasure. Since it is intelligent, and would be able to use the ring, I don't see why the ring should be lying there in a chest waiting to be looted.

Monster would use the ring, if it only had hands or even fingers. Hold a second, are fingers even necessary in 5e?

For reference, assume it only has grasping / manipulating tentacles like a [deepspawn](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Deepspawn) (although it is not one); Said tentacles are very flexible, capable of fine manipulation, and have varying thickness.

Answer (score 65):

### Rings have to be worn... just not necessarily on fingers

In the ["Beholders: Bad Dreams Come True"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/vgtm/monster-lore#BeholdersBadDreamsComeTrue) section of chapter 1 of *Volo's Guide to Monsters* (p. 15), it states under the ["Treasure"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/vgtm/monster-lore#Treasure) subheading:

> A beholder’s body can’t use many kinds of humanoid-type magic items because it doesn’t have the body parts to wear them; for example, it can’t use gloves or boots because it doesn’t have hands or feet. **But a beholder could wear magic rings on its eyestalks** or affix a magic cloak to its back, **and the items function as they would if used by a humanoid.**

Comment: This seems the most fitting when dealing with fingerless characters.

Comment: Only if the PC isn't humanoid, monsters can behave as DM rules.

Comment: @JimB PCs behave as the DM rules too

Comment: @dalem that goes without saying.  The difference is that the rules are specific on PC ring use vs monster ring use "worn as intended"

Comment: +1 Beautiful find of source material! I bet Xanathar is glad of this. ;)

Answer (score 28):

All magic rings described in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* specify the requirement that the ring be **worn**, so one would be tempted to assume that wearing them on something else than a finger would work.

However, on DMG page 140, the following is explained under ["Wearing and Wielding Items"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#WearingandWieldingItems):

> A magic item meant to be worn must be worn in its intended fashion: [...] rings [go] on the finger.

Therefore, by RAW, a ring is only truly worn when worn on the finger, and thus a character without fingers cannot use magic rings that require wearing. Whether hand-like appendages count as fingers is up to the GM.

Comment: This boils down to what counts as finger. Is a finger defined as (for the normal specimen) 4-times separated appendage covered in muscles and skin, where each part is connected to te previous and following part by a joint able to move roughly 90°, or does  anything that is effectively used to primarily manipulate the surrounding (e.g. a tentacle) to be considered a finger?

Comment: @J_F_B_M As I said, it's up to the GM to arbitrate when unclear, because the rules don't define a finger. It's much easier said than done, of course. I'd just roll with it whichever way the plot demands.

Comment: Beholders have eyestalk rings, and characters who wish to use them will need eyestalks! And as a DM, I'd try to help with that. :)

Comment: You may want to edit this answer to account for the line a few paragraphs down from the one you're quoting: "When a nonhumanoid tries to wear an item, use your discretion as to whether the item functions as intended. A ring placed on a tentacle might work, but a creature with a snakelike tail instead of legs can't wear boots." This certainly seems relevant to the question, and somewhat contradicts your claim that magic items work *only* when worn on fingers.

Comment: And a few paragraphs *above* what you've quoted is this (DMG, "Rings"): "Unless a ring's description says otherwise, a ring must be worn on a finger, **or a similar digit**, for the ring's magic to function."

Answer (score 2):

A ring needs to be worn (by a human) on a finger, not on a chain. Does it work on a toe, braided in hair? That's up to the the maker (or the DM).

If you want the monster to use it, you can let it. Otherwise, the ring is exclusively a finger ring, or the monster didn't think it would work on him/her/it, or ...

Comment: Hi, Peter, you're new welcome to the site! Check out the [tour] to see how the site is different from other Q&A and the traditional forum. Good first answer, but it could use some references.

Comment: Do you have evidence from the rulebooks that the maker of a magic ring can decide it can be worn elsewhere besides a finger?

Answer (score 2):

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* (page 139) specifically states that rings can be worn with similar digits:

> Unless a ring's description says otherwise, a ring must be worn on a finger, or a similar digit, for the ring's magic to function.

Comment: Could you point out *where* the DMG said this? I'm afraid this answer isn't much use without a more detailed citation.