# wearing requirement for a ring?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

If an extremely paranoid character has a ring of mind shielding that they never want to have removed, and enough funds to hire a surgeon to implant the ring into another body part, would the character still benefit from the abilities of the ring?

Comment: This sounds like the kind of problem that can be solved just fine with Sovereign Glue ;)

Comment: +1 Interesting. I think this needs to be revisited. This question/answer provides a different perspecitve. I guess it will be up to the DM to decide what source they want to follow, DMG or VGtM: 
https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103151/can-creatures-without-hands-and-as-a-consequence-fingers-use-rings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Page 140 of the DMG:

> A magic item meant to be worn must be donned in the intended fashion: boots go on the feet, gloves on the hands, hats and helmets on the head, and rings on the finger...

So no, implanting the ring won't confer its benefits to you.

Comment: Although this doesn't preclude creating a custom item meant to be worn differently.  Perhaps a DM could give a major break on the crafting requirements if the crafter has a ring of mind shielding to start with, and is just trying to convert it to an "arm implant of mind shielding".

Comment: theoretically, could rings go on toes?

Comment: FWIW, there is a bit in the rules regarding 'similar digit' such that fingers are not the only locale for rings... to whit ...  "a ring must be worn on a finger, *or a similar digit*, for the ring’s magic to function..." (in the Magic Rings sub section of the DMG, IIRC)