# Alternate Magical Ring placement

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, player-vs-player

I play D&D with my brother in a group. He has a character (a sorcerer) who wears his rings on his toes. He also created a campaign using his character as the enemy (NPC).
I am the only one he told where his rings were located.
When our group defeated him, I told them I was cutting off his legs and keeping them for the boots and everything inside of them.
I received a *ring of water walking* and *a ring of protection*.
Problem is once we go PvP, I can’t have them on my fingers for everyone to see and know, and I can’t have them on my toes for my brother to get them back if I die.
I want to see if I can utilize them as a piercing (and still use them) on upper 2 parts, or lower half piercings.

Comment: My character is a dragon born paladin/druid, level six

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate, but it should answer your question: [Can creatures without hands and as a consequence, fingers, use rings?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103151/can-creatures-without-hands-and-as-a-consequence-fingers-use-rings)

Comment: Did you ask your DM? If not, then we should close the question due to lack of research/clarity. If yes, what did the DM say?

Comment: I don't think I understand the dynamic. Can you clarify these things: When you say "once we go PvP" do you mean battling the other players? It seems like the other players will notice if you are walking on water or have more AC than your character otherwise would. Do you mean body piercings when you say "upper 2 parts, or lower half piercings". Traditional ear piercings would certainly still be visible; especially if they are ring sized. Why can't you just wear gloves over the rings?

Comment: @DavidCoffron I'm not sure any of that matters. The context of why a player wants to wear rings in a strange way isn't relevant to the question of whether they can.

Comment: One more question (sorry for the overload). Did your brothers **character** tell you where the rings were, or did you simply have that knowledge out of character and leveraged it in character. If the latter, this is metagaming, and I could imagine the other players being upset that they missed out on their share of possible loot because of your out of character knowledge.

Comment: Does your DM know about all of this?

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I'm more on the side of trying to help the asker get to the bottom of their concern, rather than just answer "Can you wear rings elsewhere?" Clearly they can since the group had a character use their toes

Answer (score 7):

In the DMG on p.140, the section ["Wearing and Wielding Items"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#WearingandWieldingItems) says:

> A magic item meant to be worn must be worn in its intended fashion: boots go on the feet, gloves on the hands, hats and helmets on the head, and rings on the finger.
> [...]
> When a nonhumanoid tries to wear an item, use your discretion as to whether the item functions as intended. A ring placed on a tentacle might work, but a yuan-ti with a snakelike tail instead of legs can't wear boots.

(Note that "your discretion" here means the DM's, not the player's.)

Wearing rings on toes or as piercings is not "the intended fashion", and the alternative methods of wearing items only apply to "non-humanoids", so it seems to me this idea wouldn't work from the very start. To me, putting rings on your toes or wearing them as piercings is like an elf trying to wear an extra pair of magic gloves by putting them on his ears.

So that said, it seems like your DM is ignoring the rules-as-written in this respect. They're *already* operating in house-rule territory, so asking us what the official rules say is entirely irrelevant to your situation. You're going to have to ask them about this.